# Accessing variables from module without having to specify module name in python

Tags: python

Is it possible (without using `from foo import *`) to access a variable declared in `foo` without writing `foo.variable` or using `from foo import variable`?

I need, on one hand, to access the variables easily, and it would be nice if I could look at their values (I'm using spyder, a MATLAB-inspired workspace which displays all variables and enables you to look at their values)

on the other hand, I can't use `from foo import *` because I need to use a lot of `reload`

Comment: What is wrong with `import foo; print(foo.bar)`? You *could* do `from foo import bar; print(bar)`.

Comment: Could this be useful? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2071786/python-thread-for-pre-importing-modules

Comment: @karthikr don't see how that's relevant
@LutzHorn because I copy-pasted code. It won't get into the details, but the point is I don't want to go over all the variables and add them to the import list. I'm hoping for something faster and simpler. And what's wrong with calling `foo.bar` is that I'll be doing it a lot for many different variables, and I'm just hoping for an easier solution.

Comment: Are you worried that import takes up time and resources, which will get expensive due to repeated reload?

Comment: The requirements that matter here are quite not clear to me. What do you want to achieve with this?

Comment: `from foo import a, b, c` is about as fast as you're going to get, since you need to tell the interpreter at some point which names you want in the local namespace. With regard to `reload`, this isn't really any different from `from foo import *`, but there are already reasons why using `reload` or `from foo import *` outside of testing are probably a bad idea.

Comment: @user632657 not about time or resources


@moooeeeep I'm trying to get easy access to variables without having to type `foo.variable` and without using `from foo import *`

@chepner I don't care about speed. I care about ease... I am running tests, nothing I should worry about if the code might cause problems

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `dir()` to view the contents of your local scope, or `dir(foo)` to show the contents of `foo`. This won't display their values, but you could use `locals()` or `globals()` which return dictionaries of the contents of the local or global scope.

Since they're dictionaries, you can do something like `locals()['foo']`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I just found out I can actually do this:

```
import foo
from foo import *
```

and then when I want to reload, this actually works:

```
reload(foo)
import foo
from foo import *
```