# import a module from a thread does not work

Tags: python, multithreading

The code below fails with NameError. What is wrong with the code? How can I import a module in the background thread?

```
import threading

def background_imports():
    from time import time

thread = threading.Thread(target=background_imports)
thread.setDaemon(True) # Doesn't make a difference
thread.start() 
thread.join()
print(time()) # NameError: name 'time' is not defined
```

Update: I have modules accessing PSQL on load. Loading the modules asynchronously did not reduce startup time in my case.

Update2: I see -1 for this question. Is there a way I can improve it?

Answer (score -1):

This works

```
import threading
import sys

def background_imports():
    thismodule = sys.modules[__name__]
    module = __import__("time", fromlist=["time"])
    attr = getattr(module, "time")
    setattr(thismodule, "time", attr)

thread = threading.Thread(target=background_imports)
thread.setDaemon(True)
thread.start()
thread.join()
print(time())
```

Comment: This is an old answer. I can't test it at this time. I believe the code works. I don;t know why the answer got "-1". I will welcome a feedback.